# Display PHP as an Image

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

Basically what this does is make an image for a pinned post on my wall that says "This wall has been viewed (number of) times.". This used to work for me on my free website with freewha.com, but now that I've switched to a VPS with DigitalOcean running apache (ubuntu), it does not work. It says the page cannot process the request. I was able to find out that it is an error with the bottom part after $text, however I cannot find why this is happening.

```
<?php

if(!defined('MyConst')) {
   die('Direct access not permitted');
}

$viewsOld = file_get_contents("path/views.conf");

$views = $viewsOld + 1;

file_put_contents("path/views.conf", $views);

if ($views < 10) {
$width = 305;
}
elseif ($views < 100) {
$width = 314;
}
elseif ($views < 1000) {
$width = 323;
}
elseif ($views < 10000) {
$width = 332;
}
elseif ($views < 100000) {
$width = 341;
}
elseif ($views < 1000000) {
$width = 350;
}
elseif ($views < 10000000) {
$width = 359;
}
elseif ($views < 100000000) {
$width = 368;
}
elseif ($views < 1000000000) {
$width = 377;
}
else {
}

$text = "This wall has been viewed $views times.";

$my_img = imagecreate( $width, 18 ); //width & height
$background  = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 20,   20,   20 );
$text_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 0, 255, 0 );
imagestring( $my_img, 10, 0, 0, $text, $text_colour );
imagesetthickness ( $my_img, 5 );

header( "Content-type: image/png" );
imagepng( $my_img );
imagecolordeallocate( $text_color );
imagecolordeallocate( $background );
imagedestroy( $my_img );
?>
```

I have installed php and php-common, however it still does this. Any explanation as to why this is occurring?

Comment: I think a switch block is made specifically for times like these... http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: How would I implement that into my script?

Comment: They help against multiple elseif blocks,

Comment: @Ice76 They also don't work for inequalities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script depends on the GD PHP extension. If it isn't working, you probably need to install the extension -- on Ubuntu, this would be `php-gd` (or possibly `php5-gd` if you're running an older release).